# Уместно ли сокращение "гг."?

Tags: сокращения

> ...рост с середины XX в. вплоть до 90-х гг.

Во всём тексте используем сокращения: в., г.
Уместно ли сокращение гг. в данном случае? Смотрится как-то не очень...

Comment: Я бы написал так: _... с середины вплоть до конца ХХ в._

Comment: @slava1947 Тогда уж лучше так: *во второй половине ХХ в.*

Comment: "вплоть до 90-х гг." — исключает  девяностые? Я бы писал понятней: до конца 80-х, до начала 90-х, до конца столетия, во второй половине ХХ в.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указала справочная служба русского языка, написание "до 90-х гг." является допустимым, но сокращение должно быть чем-то обосновано. Мильчин пишет, что сокращение должно быть единообразным, в частности если принято решение после цифр года слова *год*, *годы* сокращать, то  требуется сокращать и слова *век*, *века* после цифр, обозначающих столетия.

> [Вопрос № 269834](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=269834)
>   Добрый день! Как правильно писать годы в тексте (сокращенно или полностью):
>    * в 2001 г. или в 2001 году;
>    * в 2001--03 гг., или в 2001-03 годах, или в 2001-2003 годах
>    С благодарностью,
>   Коррида
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Вопрос о том, сокращать или писать "год" полностью, решается в соответствии с жанром текста. В любом случае **графическое сокращение должно быть чем-то обосновано** (стандартами документации, экономией места на листе и др.).
>
> [Вопрос № 228984](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=228984%20%20%20%20)
>   1. Интересует сокращение периодов: 2001-2007 гг. Можно ли написать: 01-07 или 1999-07? А если это 1999-2007? 99-07? Как нужно? 2. Надо ли везде прибавлять гг.? В контексте «В 90-х гг. прошлого века…» как надо писать год? Или «В 1990-х…»?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   1. Верно только: *2001--2007 гг., 1999--2007 гг.* Другие предложенные Вами варианты неверны. 2. Верно: ***в конце 90-х гг.**, в конце 90-х*.

Answer (score 2):

В исторических работах сокращения гг. и вв. являются стандартными и используются повсеместно. Данная фраза вполне допустима, но если вам не нравится, можно *с середины ХХ в.* заменить на "в послевоенный период" так как хронологически эти даты скорее всего (если речь не про страны Латинской Америки) совпадают.